# Arrange the payment options in checkout

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to edit the layout of payment options in magento that are in the

path:- **/template/checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml

```
<dl class="sp-methods" id="checkout-payment-method-load">
<?php foreach ($this->getMethods() as $_method): $_code = $_method->getCode(); ?>
    <dt class="p_method">
    <?php if( sizeof($this->getMethods()) > 1 ): ?>
        <input id="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>" value="<?php echo $_code ?>" type="radio" name="payment[method]" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_method->getTitle()) ?>" onclick="payment.switchMethod('<?php echo $_code ?>')"<?php if($this->getSelectedMethodCode()==$_code): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="radio" />
    <?php else: ?>
        <span class="no-display"><input id="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>" value="<?php echo $_code ?>" type="radio" name="payment[method]" checked="checked" class="radio" /></span>
    <?php endif; ?>
        <label for="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>"><?php echo $this->getMethodTitle($_method) ?> <?php echo $this->getMethodLabelAfterHtml($_method) ?></label>
    </dt>
    <?php if ($html = $this->getPaymentMethodFormHtml($_method)): ?>
    <dd>
        <?php echo $html; ?>
    </dd>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</dl>
```

How could I change the order from the `getMethods()` array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the order of payment methods from admin directly where every payment method has a order field that you can set

```
system > configuration > sales > payment methos
```